# Get two results while looping trough associative array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I want to get two results at a time when using while looping trough a associative array in PHP.
I need to echo two results per row, something like this:

```
<?
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $client_name = $row['client_name'];
    $review = $row['review'];
    echo('
        <div class="row">
        <div>
            <p>'.$client_name.'</p>
            <p >'.$review.'</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>'.$client_name.'</p>
            <p >'.$review.'</p>
        </div>
        </div>
    ');
    }
    }
?>
```

Right now it's giving me the same result twice rather than the next one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a counter to control the output of the outside `div` so that you get two inside `div` output for each outside one:

```
$i = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $client_name = $row['client_name'];
    $review = $row['review'];
    if ($i % 2 == 0) echo '<div class="row">';
    echo '<div><p>'.$client_name.'</p><p>'.$review.'</p></div>';
    if ($i % 2 == 1) echo '</div>';
    $i++;
}
```